# WooCommerce Images are uploading to the server but not attaching

Tags: uploads, woocommerce-offtopic

I've Created a Script that Grabs an image from an external site and it is imported to the WordPress image gallery. -> wp-admin/upload.php [Media Library]

[image: Media Gallery]

[image: The Product itself]

My Code Snipplet

```
foreach($url as $linkurl) {
    $tmp = download_url( $linkurl);

    preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/', $linkurl, $matches);

$clean = str_replace(array("%2B", "%52", "%20", "%5"), "B", basename($matches[0]));

$file_array = array(
    'name' => basename( $clean ),
    'tmp_name' => $tmp
);

if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
    @unlink( $file_array[ 'tmp_name' ] );
    return $tmp;
}

$id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, 'gallery desc' );


$value = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );

update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $id));

//update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $value ));

}
```

What am I doing Wrong

Comment: check my answer here with the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615976/upload-multiple-images-to-a-woocomerce-product/46622563#46622563

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have made a mistake in the last line. `array_push` is not doing what you are trying to achieve (check the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)) same as `update_post_meta` accepts different arguments.

Besides that WooCommerce is storing galleries in simple comma separated list like `1,45,78,34` so you should change the last line
`update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $id));`
to
`update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $id);`
or if you add multiple images then instead of $id enter comma separated list.

Comment: update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $id);                         I tried that now, does not seem like its attaching to the posts.